# Creating a random quote list using REST API

Tags: 2013, javascript, jquery, 2016, sharepoint-rest-api

I've created a custom list with 100 random quotes in the Title field. Now I am trying to adapt some existing code to select a quote at random and display it. I've gotten it to display all quote and print the random quote number to the log. Stuck on displaying only the random quote.

Any help greatly appreciated...
Thanks,
Martin

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are retrieving all 100 quotes and then randomly picking one. You might want to look at generating the random number and then selecting a single item from the list.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Tasks')/Items?$select=Title&$filter=Id eq 1
```

Replace the list name and the ID of course.

To stay with your code, and downloading all 100, try something like:

```
var theQuote = newQuote[rand].Title;
```

You could also use something like this: https://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=6074070440029916342#editor/target=post;postID=1999918282449567995;onPublishedMenu=allposts;onClosedMenu=allposts;postNum=0;src=postname

Comment: That fixed it.... much appreciated!